# Work computer, windows 10, no iTunes, stop iphone pop up "allow this device..."

Tags: iphone, usb, charging

- Windows 10 Professional (10.0.17134.228) and iPhone 6 (iOS 11.4.1).
- iTunes is not installed, can't have it, and don't want it. (Work computer)
- Under:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple , there is no 
>   \Mobile Device Support\Drivers

When I connect iPhone to USB for charging, there's no pop-up message in Windows, but a popup to allow this device on iPhone, every time!

How do I get rid of it?

The most commonly cited fix, updating driver manually pointing it to the folder mentioned above is not (!) an option, since the path is incomplete, meaning folder/s mentioned are missing.